# converting byte[] into long in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

iam getting from c.dot net web service

```java
byte[] data = new byte[] {-33, -96,0, 0, 0,0,0,0};
```

I want to convert this into long value
  I tried this

```java
long result = (long)ByteBuffer.wrap(index).getInt();
```

I am getting the result as `-543162368` wheras actual value is `41183`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you want to call `getLong()` instead of `getInt()` on the buffer.

However, the data you're receiving is little-endian, which means that it starts with the low order byte first. `ByteBuffers` are constructed as default with big endian order. You need to set the order to `LITTLE_ENDIAN` to get the correct value out.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(index)
buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
long result = buffer.getLong();
```

Since you apparently can't set the byte order or use getLong, you will need to do it like this:

```
// Reverse array
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
   byte temp = data[i];
   data[i] = data[8-i];
   data[8-i] = temp;
}

// Get two ints and shift the first int into the high order bytes 
// of the result.
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
long result = ((long)buffer.getInt()) << 32;
result |= (long)buffer.getInt();
```

`result` should now contain the value.

Comment: but getLong() is not supported in blackberry and also ByteOrder is also not supported in blackberry

Comment: Reverse the array manually then and call get int twice, casting the first result to a long and shift it 32 places left and OR it with the result of the second call.

Comment: i did as u suggested Mr.Dervall but iam getting the result as zero but i tried like this and got the result  long l = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
   l <<= 8;
   l ^= (long) bytes[i] & 0xff;
  }
  return l;

Comment: That was not what I suggested. Take a look at the edited post to see what I meant.